# Is it possible to call several methods from an anonymous class?

Tags: java, anonymous-class

I want to know if its possible this in some way pls java 7 or 8

```
public class App{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                //Something
            }
        }.start().setName("Something") //Here!!
        //Something
    }
}
```

Comment: Not like that. It would require `start` to return the `Thread` object - which it doesn't (it's a void method)

Comment: maybe: `Thread thread = new Thread() { ...},` `thread.setName(...),`  `thread.setPriority(...);` and `thread.start(),` (but would be better to call the constructor with a `Runable` instead of extending `Thread`)

Comment: This looks like [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377). What is the situation you are in and what exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: no, not XY problem IMO, apparently OP just want to change name of thread and start it

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger if that's the case, asking how to do what is asked in the question *is* an XY problem.

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger OP example indeed shows some attempt to modify Thread settings, but title seems to be more general. I am not claiming that it *is* XYproblem, but that it *can* be. For instance "call several methods from an anonymous class?" can also represent situation like `new Object(){ void newMethod1(){..} void newMethod2(){..}};`. How can we call `newMethod1()` 
 and `newMethod2()` here (since they are "methods from an anonymous class")?

Comment: OK, title is more of an *XY problem*...

Comment: Please don't add [solved] title hacks here. We have a purpose-made answer acceptance system, which you've used already - that is fine on its own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible since neither `start()` nor `setName()` returns the thread. The created anonymous class, is a subclass of `Thread`, so it can be assigned to such a variable:

```
Thread thread = new Thread {
    // something
};
thread.setName(...);
thread.setPriority(...);
thread.start();
```

or using functional notation:

```
Thread thread = new Thread( () -> { ... } );
thread.setName(...);
thread.setPriority(...);
thread.start();
```

and my preferred (no additional class being created), using method reference:

```
    Thread thread = new Thread(this::runInThread);
    thread.setName(...);
    thread.setPriority(...);
    thread.start();
    ...
}

private void runInThread() {
    // something to run in thread
}
```

<sup>added `setPriority()` just to have more calls</sup>

Answer (score 0):

In your example, it is not possible as `start()` returns `void`. However, depends on the implementation of the method you are calling. In some design, we design `(Builder pattern/ Fluent)` method generally returns `this`, in that case, `method chaining` is possible. For your example, you can do it like below.

```
Thread t = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
    }
};
t.setName("Something");
t.start();
```

Comment: thanks now i edited the Thread class start() method to return this and i can do it

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to declare, name and start the thread in a single statement, just use the constructor which specifies the thread name:

```
new Thread("Something") { ... }.start();
```